# Flutter Geo Locator give wrong latitude and longitude

Tags: flutter, geolocation, gps

Flutter geolocator gives me always this latitude and longitude 37.4219983, -122.084 respectively, which is not my real address so how can I improve it.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you are using the emulator. That's the default test location given to emulator. If you want to change the location you can change location through extended controls of the emulator.

[image]

Running the Flutter application on your device will fetch your live location.

Comment: Running it on my device gives me the same wrong location

Answer (score 1):

yes, it solved after I run the application in mobile phone